# mail.google.com is used to download the attachment instead of mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com in Gsuite Account

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, google-workspace

Whenever any attachment is downloaded on free Gmail account then the attachment is getting downloaded through the URL "mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com". But when the attachment is downloaded using g-suite Gmail account then the content is getting downloaded using mail.google.com (instead of "mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com").

Is this is expected behavior that attachment content getting downloaded from "mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com" (instead of "mail.google.com)".

Attachment should be always downloaded from mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com instead of mail.gmail.com